# 2 questions on writing a valid CSS 2.1 stylesheet without errors

Tags: html, css, w3c-validation

I have two questions on how to write a correct/without error CSS 2.1 stylesheet:

1. The CSS validator says to me that `overflow-y: scroll` is not supported on CSS 2.1. So, what can I use for the same effect?
2. I have something like 500 warnings that say *Same colors for color and background-color in two contexts .error and .contact3* (about different classes, of course), what does it mean? And how can I resolve this?

Comment: Why do you care so much about CSS 2.1?

Comment: Because ordinarily you'd be designing for browsers, not for specifications. If `overflow-y` is going to be supported by the software used by your visitors, then it doesn't matter if it's valid CSS 2.1 or not. (It is valid CSS, after all.) So I was wondering why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. CSS validator say to me that overflow-y: scroll is not supported on CSS 2.1. So, what can I use for the same valid effect?

They're not valid because they were introduced in CSS3. In CSS 2.1, you can only set `overflow` for both horizontal and vertical at the same time.

Most browsers support `overflow-y` now, so I would worry less about 2.1 validation (as your CSS will be valid with a CSS 3 validator).  You can use `overflow: auto` as a fallback for unsupported browsers.

> 2. I have somethings like 500 warning that say Same colors for color and background-color in two contexts .error and .contact3 (about different classes, of course) , what does it means? And how can I resolve this trouble?

The problem is what it says it is.  If you have the `background-color` the same as the `color`, it generates a warning because any text will not be visible to the user.  If that is your intention, you would be better off setting the foreground `color` to `transparent` on those elements:

```
.error {
    color: transparent;
}
```

Beyond that, though, warnings are just warnings and your CSS is valid with them.  Warnings exist to let you know that you *may* have made a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `overflow:auto;`  This will add scrollbars when needed.